# AJAX POST to laravel returning 404 not found

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to process POST data from ajax to laravel controllers but I can't access it. Here is what I am doing in AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/complete_ca_fin',
     data: {fin_id: id},
     success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#modal_complete').modal('hide');
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0  }, "slow");

      $('#message_form').empty().css('display','block').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').text('Finished Good CA has been successfully completed.');
      $('#message_form').fadeOut(4000);

      setTimeout(function(){
          window.location = '/quality_control';
      }, 3000);
      refresh_check = true;
      window.onbeforeunload = null;

     },
     error: function (data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
     } // end of error

  }); // ajax
```

`id` should be accessed in the controller. Here is my route

`Route::post('/complete_ca_fin', 'DatasheetController@complete_ca_fin');`

And here is my controller

```
public function complete_ca_fin(Request $request) {
      $id = $request->id;
      $complete_ca = FinishedCA::findOrFail($id);

      if ($complete_ca){
        $complete_ca->status = '5';
        $complete_ca->save();
        return 'success';
      }

      //return 'success';

    }
```

When I try to return `$id` just to test I noticed that it is empty ( I don't if it has anything to do with it ) but I know that `var id` in the ajax has a value because I tested it in the console.

Here is a sample of the console log. 37 is the value of the id so there should be a value in the controller
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `findOrfail` which means it will throw a 404 if there is no email, you want to be validating if it exists, not 404'ing of not

```
public function complete_ca_fin(Request $request) {
  $id = $request->id;
  $complete_ca = FinishedCA::find($id);

  if ($complete_ca->exists()){
    $complete_ca->status = '5';
    $complete_ca->save();
    return 'success';
  }

  //return 'success';

}
```

Comment: I think I am losing the value on request, I tried doing this `$id = $request->id;return $id;` and it returns empty. Can you help me? I think that's why it failing.

Comment: I got it not now. It turns out I need to use `data: {variable: value}` on my ajax request

Comment: Yeh sorry should have mentioned you needed to add a key to the var. Glad you got it sorted, for future reference `orFail` will return a 404 response if the item has not been found, using just `find` you have to check for null yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Input::get('id');` instead of request , So your method will like this

```
public function complete_ca_fin(Request $request) {
      $id = Input::get('id');
      $complete_ca = FinishedCA::findOrFail($id);

      if ($complete_ca){
        $complete_ca->status = '5';
        $complete_ca->save();
        return 'success';
      }

      //return 'success';

    }
```